# convert short form of tree string(parentheses) into full form

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree, binary-tree, expression-trees

I want to convert a short form of a tree string expression (with parentheses) into the full form of it.

This is an example tree expression:

```
intput: ((((XX(XXX(XX 
output: ((((XX)(XX))X)(XX))
```

and this tree looks like:
[image: this].

can some one provides me full code or at least some part of code in C++?

other example:

```
input: (S((SS(S(S(((S(SSSS 

output: (S((SS)(S(S(((S(SS))S)S)))))
```

Comment: _"Is there any way to do it in C++?"_ Probably, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an inorder tree traversal process.
**Root-->Left-->Right**.

If you want I can write the full solution which will take some time.

Can You give me an example code(I mean is there any code snippets given)?
Or I have to write tree-building code and then output?

look at you code:
Let answer string = "";

step 01: root -->(, answer = "(", go left

step02: root --->(,   answer = "((", go left

step 03: root -->(  answer = "(((", go left

step04: root --> ( answer = "((((, go left

step 05: root ---> x answer = "((((x, there is no left, go right of step 04

step 06: root--> x, answer = "((((xx, there is no left, right, so add ")"

so the answer will be = "((((xx), and go right of step 03

step 07: root -->(, answer = "(((xx)(, go left

step 08: root--> x answer = "((((xx)(x, no left go right of step 07

step 09: root--> x answer = "((((xx)(xx, there is no left or right , go back, add")"

so the answer will be= "((((xx)(xx)

same way you can solve the rest of the tree.

**Note** If there is no child node, and the node is right of parent node add ")"(closing bracket)

Comment: full code please

Comment: no code snippets, i want to just convert short form to full form, just that not more

Comment: look at you code: Let answer string = "";

step 01: root -->(, answer = "(", go left

step02: root --->(,   answer = "((", go left

step 03: root -->(  answer = "(((", go left

step04: root --> ( answer = "((((, go left

step 05: root ---> x answer = "((((x, there is no left, go right of step 04 root

step 06: root--> x, answer = "((((xx, there is no left, right, so add ")"

so the answer will be = "((((xx), and go right of step 03 root

step 07: root -->(, answer = "(((xx)(, go left

step 08: root--> x answer = "((((xx)(x, no left go right of step 07

Comment: step 09: root--> x answer = "((((xx)(xx, there is no left or right , go back, add ")"
so the answer will be= "((((xx)(xx)

Comment: @amirking59 I have added some steps in answer.